# How to chain observables with different intervals in RxJava?

Tags: android, rx-java, delay, reactivex

I saw a whole lot of posts for having `Rx` delaying each emission of an event : [How to make countdown timer with RxJS Observables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34921555/how-to-make-countdown-timer-with-rxjs-observables), [How to use RxJava Interval Operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37652952/how-to-use-rxjava-interval-operator), [Adding delay between Observable Items RxJava](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39284120/adding-delay-between-observable-items-rxjava), [RxJava delay for each item of list emitted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33291245/rxjava-delay-for-each-item-of-list-emitted), and others.

Though, I didn't see any for chaining with different delays.

Basically, I have a Textview and a list of letters, and I'd like to :

- set the text to the first letter
- wait 1500ms
- set the text to null
- wait 500ms
- set the text to the second letter
- wait 1500ms
- set the text to null
- wait 500ms
- repeat for the entire list

A code implementation could maybe look somehow like this (but I guess `doThing()` is nonsense in `Rx`, and `delay()` is not meant for this) :

```
Observable.fromArray(new String[]{"A", "B", "C", "D", "E"})
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .delay(500L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .doThing((String i) -> {
            textView.setText("");
            Log.d("XXX", "MainActivity :: onCreate (110): letter="+ i);
        })
        .delay(1500L, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
        .doThing((String i) -> {
            textView.setText(i);
            Log.d("XXX", "MainActivity :: onCreate (110): letter="+ i);
        });
```

How can I achieve this with Rx ?

EDIT : I could use the answer from [rxjava delay: How to get variable delay on each item emitted from a list?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39012715/rxjava-delay-how-to-get-variable-delay-on-each-item-emitted-from-a-list) with a list of letters where one letter on two is special (null maybe ?), but it seems overcomplicated.

Comment: you can try using zip or concat map. basically you have two observables, one for your data, one for your delay (alternating 500/1500 delays). then you combine them together. (yup,  that's the answer from your last link)

Comment: @AngelKoh You mean my last link in my edit or in my intro ? If in my edit, I'd think such a common task were doable in a less tedious way. If in my intro, could you provide a little example as an answer ? That would help me a lot !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Sequence**: `A (1500ms) null (500ms) B (1500ms) null (500ms) C (500ms) null (1500ms)`

```
textAnimationDisposable = Observable.fromArray("A", "B", "C")
        .concatMap(string ->
              Observable.merge(
                 Observable.just(string),
                 Observable.just("").delay(1500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
              )
              .concatWith(Observable.<String>empty().delay(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
        )
        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
        .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
        .subscribe(string -> textView.setText(string));
```

The [last solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39017062/2397822) you linked is quite useful for controlling the delay of each item separatly.

Comment: This seems very promising, thanks ! I clarified my sequence, it corresponds to your 2nd code. Unfortunately, your code doesn't work : as is, I get a `ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException`, and with some more `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` inside the `concatMap()`, I never see the `null` text.

Comment: Ah yeah, the created observable within `concatMap()` ran on the background thread and tried to change the layout from there. That caused the `ViewRootImpl$CalledFromWrongThreadException`.

I tried it out within an android project, updating the answer...

Comment: The sequence still has an isseu: The empty string comes after the text. After the last item, the textview will be empty.

Comment: The sequence could be restarted when completed to eliminate this. Also, one could check within `concatMap` if `string` is the last item in the list and not emit the empty string. Then the last string would stay in the text view.

Comment: Great, this works like a charm ! Actually, I added a `Action()` as `onComplete`, so after the last, the "game" ends.